# Minolta MD on Nikon F-Mount

Tags: lens, vintage

I have recently bought a vintage lens 135mm f2.8 from Auto Revenon, with m42 bajonet. And to mount it on my nikon d7000 I need to install an adapter with correction lens. Otherwise the focus range will be to short and it can't reach infinity. I have read that is because of the distance from the lens to the sensor.

And I would like to know if I also need correction lens for other vintage lenses, especially for minolta md?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a correction lens in any adapter for non-Nikon F mount lenses on a Nikon F mount system.  It is because of the registration distance.

If you plan to use old lenses on a system you would be better to use a MILC system with a short registration distance.  There are many adapters that allow lenses to be adapted cheaply to MILC systems and they do not require any additional optical correction in the adapters.

Comment: not a fans of milc though. But a neat advice. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Say DSLM, Milc sounds so Milquetoast.